# I want it to say "Reserved" and replace the checkbox when a booking has been completed in the given timeslot the user has booked

Tags: javascript, python, html

We're a small university project group trying to create a simple booking site for study rooms. The function I can't seem to get to work is that I want the checkbox the user clicks to check the timeslots for booking replaced by the text "Reserved", which makes it so the other users can't reserve the same timeslot on the given day. I have tried to link it to our sqlite3 database so it stores the booked_timeslots so it knows where to put reserved. But nothing seem to work. I can provide further snippets if needed.

I tried to connect to the db and tried the local.storage one, but im not sure if i did them correctly or not. We're all very new to this coding stuff.

Here's some snippets:
We have similar ones for each weekday. For calender that the user has to click the checkboxes to book timeslots.

```
<div id="Monday" class="tabcontent"> <!-- The content of the tab -->
            <table class="tableAvailability">
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Availability</th>
                {% for timeslot in ['07:00 - 08:00', '08:00 - 09:00', '09:00 - 10:00', '10:00 - 11:00', '11:00 - 12:00', '12:00 - 13:00', '13:00 - 14:00','14:00 - 15:00', '15:00 - 16:00'] %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ timeslot }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if timeslot in booked_timeslots %}
                            Reserved
                        {% else %}
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-{{loop.index}}" name="timeslots" value="{{ timeslot }}" data-time="{{ timeslot }}" onclick="displayCheckbox()">
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
```

And i tried doing this here. This way, I were passing the booked_timeslots data from my Flask application to my JavaScript file, in which the data could be used to manipulate the checkboxes on the page. But it didnt work:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][name=timeslots]');

    checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        var timeslot = checkbox.getAttribute('data-time');
        if (bookedTimeslots.includes(timeslot)) {
            checkbox.disabled = true;
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(' Reserved');
            checkbox.parentNode.appendChild(textNode);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: you run `JavaScrip` code at start but maybe you should add `Listener` which will check all time if checkbox was changed (and it should send result to `Flask` using `fetch()`). Or you could use `CSS` to hide `checkbox and show `Reserved` without using `JavaScript. But it still would need `JavaScript` to run `fetch()` to send information to `Flask`

Comment: now I see `onclick="displayCheckbox()` (so you don't need `Listener`) but where you define `displayCheckbox`? It should run code which you have in `checkboxes.forEach()`

Comment: if you don't use `fetch()` in `JavaScript` to send changes to `Flask` then you need to  put `<input>`  in `<form>` and use `<button type="submit">` to send it to server when user press button. And if you use `<form method="POST">` then Flask needs `@app.route(..., methods=["GET", "POST"])`

Answer (score 0):

You have `<input ... onclick=displayCheckbox()>`
but you forgot `function displayCheckbox()`.

And you need `this` in `onclick=displayCheckbox(this)` to send clicked `checkbox` to function.

```html
{% else %}
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  id="checkbox-{{loop.index}}" 
  name="timeslots" 
  value="{{ timeslot }}" 
  data-time="{{ timeslot }}" 
  onclick="displayCheckbox(this)"
>
{% endif %}
```

```js
<script>
function displayCheckbox(checkbox) {
    console.log('displayCheckbox');

    checkbox.disabled = true;
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(' Reserved');
    checkbox.parentNode.appendChild(textNode);    
}
</script>
```

Other problem is to send this to `Flask`.

You may use `fetch(url, ...)` in `JavaScript` to send it to some `url` in `Flask`.

You could get `checkbox.value` and send to `Flask` but it gives only `timeslot`.
You may need to add `Monday` to `value="{{ timeslot }}"` to send complete information.
ie. `value="Monday,{{ timeslot }}"`

Or you could put `timeslot` and day name directly as parameter.
ie. `onclick=displayCheckbox(this, 'Monday', '{{ timeslot }}')`

---

Full working code which

- adds text `Reserved` when user click `checkbox`
- sends `timeslot` and `dayname` to `Flask` using `fetch('/reserved')`
- gets data in `Flask`

(Maybe it may need to secure url `/reserved` but this part I skiped.)

[image]

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Reservations</title>
<style>
.red {color: red}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<div id="Monday" class="tabcontent"> <!-- The content of the tab -->
    <table class="tableAvailability">
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Availability</th>
        {% for timeslot in ['07:00 - 08:00', '08:00 - 09:00', '09:00 - 10:00', '10:00 - 11:00', '11:00 - 12:00', '12:00 - 13:00', '13:00 - 14:00','14:00 - 15:00', '15:00 - 16:00'] %}
        <tr {% if timeslot in booked_timeslots %}class="red"{% endif %}>
            <td>{{ timeslot }}</td>
            <td>
                {% if timeslot in booked_timeslots %}
                    Not Available
                {% else %}
                    <input 
                      type="checkbox" 
                      id="checkbox-{{loop.index}}" 
                      name="timeslots" 
                      value="Monday,{{ timeslot }}" 
                      data-day="Monday"
                      data-time="{{ timeslot }}" 
                      onclick="displayCheckbox(this)"
                    >
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>

<script>
function displayCheckbox(checkbox) {
    console.log('Run displayCheckbox()');
    
    checkbox.disabled = true;
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(' Reserved');
    checkbox.parentNode.appendChild(textNode);
    
    data = {'value': checkbox.value};
    
    fetch('/reserved', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },        
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log("Status: " + data['status']));    
}
</script>
</body>
</html>''', booked_timeslots=['10:00 - 11:00', '12:00 - 13:00'])


@app.route('/reserved', methods=['POST'])
def reserved():
    #print('args :', request.args)
    #print('form :', request.form)
    print('json :', request.json)
    #print('files:', request.files)
    #print('data :', request.data)

    data = request.json
    day, timeslot = data['value'].split(',')
    
    print('day:', day)
    print('timeslot:', timeslot)
    
    return {'status': "OK"}
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True 
    #app.run(threaded=False, processes=3)
    #app.run(use_reloader=False)
    app.run()
```

---

[Using the Fetch API - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: I don't seem to understand your answer... or how to read the comments properly it seems. Your code looks alot like what I've tried in the past, but never worked. Do you need more information about my code?

Comment: If you tried something similar then you could show it in question. In answer you have full working code so you can compare it with your code to see differences. First difference is `function displayCheckbox(checkbox)` which you don't have it. You use `onload` to run similar code but it is wrong idea. You have to run it in `displayCheckbox()` which you assigned with `onclick=...`